# Get direct firebase node value

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase image structure]

As you can see I have stream,subjects and postkey in my structure now I want to get the value of subject placed at last,
Now the scenario is I have knowledge of path only to **"posts-by-subjects/stream/electronics and communication/subjects"** and no knowledge of of **postkey** and the **last subject node value**.
Then how can I get the **value of last subject node**.

Answer (score 0):

**As no one could not give the answer after a full day work on this i get my answer on my own**

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("posts-by-subjects").child(selectedStream).child("subjects").getRef();
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                ArrayList postkeys = new ArrayList();
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    postkeys.add(child.getValue().toString());
                }
                final String[] subjectName = new String[postkeys.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i <= postkeys.size() - 1; i++) {
                    int lenght = postkeys.get(i).toString().length();
                    subjectName[i] = postkeys.get(i).toString().substring(9, lenght - 1);
                    if (!(subjects.contains(subjectName[i]))) {
                        subjects.add(subjectName[i]);
                    }
                }
           }
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```